# Spring SAML integration with WSO2 Identity server "Validation of protocol message signature failed"

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have Spring SAML sample application. I have configured WSO2 identity server metadata into sample application. I am able to login into sample application using WSO2 identity server as identity provider.

Now I am adding support for multiple identity provider for sample application. So I have configured Okta(external idp) in WSO2 identity server and imported okta certificate into Spring SAML sample application keystore. But I am getting

```
2017-01-18 13:49:22.083 DEBUG 7416 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.s.SAMLProcessingFilter             : Incoming SAML message is invalid

org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed
    at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.doEvaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:138) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.evaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:107) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BasicSecurityPolicy.evaluate(BasicSecurityPolicy.java:51) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.processSecurityPolicy(BaseMessageDecoder.java:132) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:83) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]

2017-01-18 13:49:22.095 DEBUG 7416 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.s.SAMLProcessingFilter             : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Incoming SAML message is invalid

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Incoming SAML message is invalid
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed
    at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.doEvaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:138) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.evaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:107) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BasicSecurityPolicy.evaluate(BasicSecurityPolicy.java:51) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.processSecurityPolicy(BaseMessageDecoder.java:132) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:83) ~[openws-1.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 58 more
```

I tried adding Okta metadata directly into sample application and it worked. But when I am trying to implement it with wso2 identity server it gives error. I have imported WSO2 public cert and Okta cert both into sample application's keystore.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding.
Either you tell Spring SAML app (acting as the SP) to use multiple IdPs (and offer you a choice during SP-initiated SSO), then you don' need to have th Okta IdP meta data in WSO2)
 Or you configure WSO2 SAML IdP as an IdP Proxy (and make Spring SAML SP use an IdP Proxy), then you don't need Okta IdP meta data in Spring SAML app.

Currently it seems you are mixing both scenarios.

Comment: Actually, I have configured Spring SAML app as SP in WSO2 IS. What i want to do is I will add multiple identity providers in WSO2 like Okta, Office 365 and those will be linked to Spring SAML app using WSO2. I want WSO2 as a middleware between my Spring SAML app and other identity providers. 

This scenario worked with TRAVELOCITY application(sample app provided by WSO2). I can login to travelocity using Okta credential via WSO2 identity server. But its not working with Spring SAML App.

Comment: This works as long as WSO2 works as so called IdP-Proxy and the applications (SPs) are configured to use an IdP-Proxy. By default Spring SAML sample app is not configured to use an IdP-Proxy and you have to add

<property name="includeScoping" value="true"/>
<property name="proxyCount" value="1"/>

for org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions

Comment: "Validation of protocol message signature failed" most likely means that the public key (part of the certificate in the SAML MetaData ... KeyInfo "signing" Element) does not "match" the private key used to sign the message.

The config I was talking about is to make Spring SAML app work with IdP proxy. An IdP Proxy acts as an IdP to the SP (the Spring SAML app) and in turn as SP for the actual IdP, in your case Okta.

You may first try to get SP-initiated SSO working from Spring SAML app to WSO2 acting as IdP. If this works, make SP-initiated SSO from WSO2 SP to Okta IdP work.

Comment: Thank You @BernhardThalmayr. It worked. Now i can login to application through Okta using WSO2 as IDP proxy. SP initiated flow is working but IDP initiated flow have some problems. For IDP initiated its giving error on WSO2 as Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache.

Comment: there is no way to make IdP-initiated work ... how should it work?

Only the AuthnRequest message offers ProxyCount, but this is only available in SP-initiated scenario.